# Using Conditions and Parameters in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a condition based on an optional parameter. The option is whether to run some additional installation from my userData script for an EC2 deployment.

The parameters and conditions look like this:

```
Parameters: 
  EnvType: 
    Description: Option to install New Relic Infrastructure.
    Default: apm
    Type: String
  AllowedValues: 
    - apm
    - +infra
```

Then my EC2 Resource with conditional startup scripts

```
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
     InstanceType: t2.micro
     ImageId: ami-9c9443e3  #Amazon Linux AMI in Tokyo
     KeyName: tokyocloudformation
     IamInstanceProfile: 'S3EC2'
     SecurityGroupIds:
         - !Ref myNewSecurityGroup   
     UserData:
        Condition: apmOnly
        Fn::Base64:
          |
            #!/bin/bash
            installstuff
      Condition: addInfrastructureAgent
        Fn::Base64:
          |
           #!/bin/bash
           installstuff
           installsomeotherstuff
```

The error message I'm getting is:
Template validation error: Template format error: Unresolved dependencies [EnvTyp]. Cannot reference resources in the Conditions block of the template

I get what the error is saying I believe, but it doesn't seem to fit with the examples given by AWS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html . 
This AWS example clearly uses a !Ref in the Conditions block.

```
  EnvType: 
    Description: Environment type.
    Default: test
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: 
      - prod
      - test
    ConstraintDescription: must specify prod or test.
  Conditions: 
    CreateProdResources: !Equals [ !Ref EnvType, prod ]
```

Can someone provide some feedback on how to implement this conditional or why this error message is being thrown for this implementation?

Comment: You should condition the script not the resource. The resource is identical in each case. Only the script changes.

Comment: Thanks!  I also found where I'd need the following (cfn-hup)  to implement conditionally in userData, so that the script runs again on restarts or updates from cfn. Leaving here for posterity. 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html), Conditions should be used at the top level of the resource you want to conditionally create.

Putting a `Condition` inside the Instance `UserData` section isn't supported.

To use Conditions in your situation, you'd want separate Resources conditionally created based on the Parameter.

```
Resources:
  Ec2InstanceAPMOnly:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Condition: apmOnly
    Properties:
     InstanceType: t2.micro
     ImageId: ami-9c9443e3  #Amazon Linux AMI in Tokyo
     KeyName: tokyocloudformation
     IamInstanceProfile: 'S3EC2'
     SecurityGroupIds:
         - !Ref myNewSecurityGroup   
     UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            installstuff

  Ec2InstanceWithInfrastructureAgent:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Condition: addInfrastructureAgent
    Properties:
     InstanceType: t2.micro
     ImageId: ami-9c9443e3  #Amazon Linux AMI in Tokyo
     KeyName: tokyocloudformation
     IamInstanceProfile: 'S3EC2'
     SecurityGroupIds:
         - !Ref myNewSecurityGroup   
     UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            installstuff
            installsomeotherstuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conditions in userData as well. i followed this post https://www.singlestoneconsulting.com/blog/cloudformation-mapping-and-conditionals-making-your-templates-more-universal/ and it worked perfactlly

Comment: The link is broken :(